# License file not found when using morena java based application

Tags: java

I have downloaded demo version of morena 7 but i when i run through localhost , it shows me an error License file not found .

I would appreciate if anyone can help .as there is a license file in morena folder named morena_license.jar

Answer (score 0):

Following their [tutorial](http://www.gnome.eu/Morena/doc/tutorial7.html) all Jar files should be in the `CLASSPATH`.

Which has a different meaning then `being in the same directory`.